# Remove ubuntu and grub completely on UEFI, dual boot with windows 10 on legacy

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows, grub-efi

I have windows 10 installed on legacy boot. Recently I installed ubuntu and accidentally installed it on UEFI, but now I can't enter my windows 10 anymore.

I tried uninstalling my ubuntu and delete all the partition, but I redirected to the grub minimal bash like. I can exit it and now go to my windows. Turn out there's still the system partition and somehow I can't delete it. How do I remove the grub and ubuntu files completely?

Comment: I don't know how to get the windows boot back, but if you go into bios and set your bios to boot legacy ubuntu... you could reinstall ubuntu in legacy mode and you should be able to dual boot your windows from grub... as long as you dont delete any windows partitions!!! installing ubuntu in legacy mode will start off with the purple boot screen vice the black one for UEFI... you may want to get rid of the UEFI partition during your install too... it should be visible when setting up your partitions if you do it manually

Comment: It sounds like you've already deleted Ubuntu.  GRUB is a GNU tool that is used to boot Ubuntu, it's located in /boot/grub/ of the Ubuntu partition, however if the Ubuntu partition has already been deleted, the `grub` program is also gone, you've only got a MBR pointer that's now invalid as pointing in the wrong location. I've already suggested using the `bootrec` command from within windows 10 (which will correct the pointer, on your last question)

Comment: there's still the system partition of ubuntu which i can't delete nor access through windows. I think this is the cause, but i don't know how to resolve this

Comment: UEFI install moved boot flag to ESP - efi system partition. But Windows in BIOS mode needs boot flag on the primary NTFS partition with its boot files, usually sda1, even though main install is sda2. But you may have a recovery partition first changing which partiiton has boot files. The bootmgr & /boot/BCD are the boot files in the boot partition with other support files.